# Quickblox: how find out whether the user is online for android?

Tags: android, authentication, chat, quickblox

Is there any way to find out whether the Quickblox user is online with ANDROID ? I'm using Quickblox ANDROID SDK.

I know this question already posted by IOS user , but ANDROID and IOS code are not equal in QB API calls.

There is no method/doc given in QB API documentation.

In Advance Thank You....

Answer (score 1):

You can use contact list (Roster) and Presences API for this purpose

http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/roster.html

Comment: Igor , thank you.....But i am not using this igniterealtime.com code....I have developed my own code

Comment: I'm using the Roster roster = connection.getRoster(); call but there are no entries.  Also, what is the "Presences API"? Is that a QB or SMACK API?

Comment: It's SMACK API. In order to know user's status you should add it to your roster (contact list)